# Bernouilli inequality for exponential sequence

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

I want to show that $$\forall\space n\ge 1: \left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n\le 2$$ using Bernouilli's inequality. I don't see a starting point since the inequality $$(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$$ $\forall\space n\ge 1$ and $x\ge -1$ only gives us a "greater or equal" starting point. Any tips?

Comment: Why Bernoulli? Just show that the sequence is increasing, and converges to $\,\sqrt{e} \lt 2\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for your comment. I already showed that the sequence is increasing in a previous question, but in this exercise we assume that we do not know the limit of this sequence yet (this is the goal of the exercise, at the end at least). For Bernouilli, the question states to use it but I don't see how to do it. Maybe Bernouilli has no place here after all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n \le \frac{1}{\left(1-\cfrac{1}{2n}\right)^n} \le \frac{1}{1 - n \cdot \cfrac{1}{2n}}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I see you used Bernouilli in the second inequality. I managed to prove your first inequality but can you give a bit of intuition as to why it is true? My approach was : $1+\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}\le\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n}}$ and so this should apply for the sequence $1+\frac{1}{2n}$ as well.

Comment: @Sadem First inequality comes from $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2 \le a^2$ for $a=1,b=\frac{1}{2n}$.